# how can I break the rows of an halign nicely across pages?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, plain-tex

I'm trying to print large tables for my own consumption (I'm using Plain TeX and eplain). They are tables of publications and I just want to be able to look at them. Each table will have a variable number of rows, possibly in the hundreds. Because the rows have a lot of content, the pages need to be landscape.

My problem is that the output of the code below is missing rows on the bottom of the table. I expected TeX to insert a page break and continue the rows on the next page. How can I do this?

FWIW, the Advanced TeXbook says that breaks should occur naturally; and TeX by Topic talks about having to do special things to discourage page breaks. I'm doing none of those but I still get no page breaks.

```
\input eplain

{
%% sets up the output page so it's landscape
\paperheight = 8.5truein
\paperwidth = 11truein
\pdfpageheight = 8.5truein
\pdfpagewidth = 11truein
\leftmargin = .1in
\rightmargin = .1in
\hsize = 10.8in
\vsize = 8in

\def\raggedcenter{\leftskip=0pt plus4em \rightskip=\leftskip%
  \parfillskip=0pt \spaceskip=.3333em \xspaceskip=.5em
  \pretolerance=9999 \tolerance=9999 \parindent=0pt
  \hyphenpenalty=9999 \exhyphenpenalty=9999}

\font\rm=pplr7t at 8pt
\font\it=pplri7t at 8pt
\font\sc=cmcsc10 at 8pt
\font\tt=pltt10 at 7pt
\font\entryfont=cmr8
\font\headerfont=cmr10

\rm

{\raggedcenter Symbolic Execution

}\vskip 10pt

\newdimen\hsizecol
\hsizecol=\hsize
\divide\hsizecol by4
\baselineskip=9pt
\tabskip=0pt\halign to \hsize{%
%% cite key
  \raggedcenter\tt#\hbox to 10pt{}&
%% authors
  \tabskip=0pt plus 1fil\vbox{\hsize=\hsizecol\raggedcenter#}&
%% title
  \raggedcenter\it#\hbox to 10pt{}&
%% other tags
  \raggedcenter#\tabskip=0pt\cr
%
  \headerfont Cite Key&
  \headerfont Authors&
  \headerfont Title&
  \headerfont Tags\hfil\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
%
  \noalign{\hrule}
  Anand+:TACAS2008&
  Saswat Anand and Patrice Godefroid and Nikolai Tillmann&
  Demand-Driven Compositional Symbolic Execution&
  hi\cr
}}\bye
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you haven't taken account of `\hoffset` and `\voffset` which you want to set to `-1in` if you want the origin for measuring page sizes and margins to be in the corner of the page rather than 1 inch in. (If you add that default inch on to your `\vsize` and `\hsize` you will see that is greater than the pdf page size you have set, so it is being cropped.)

Also you have a spurious `{` at the beginning which generates an error about `\end` being in a group at the end of the document.

Ah the main issue actually is the rules are preventing page breaking. Change

```
\hrule
```

to

```
 \hrule\penalty-5
```

in each case.

Comment: If I take out all the page dimension settings (in that first block), the problem persists. Does it persist for you? (And I believe eplain will adjust `\hoffset` and `\voffset` when you set `\leftmargin` and `\rightmargin`.)

Comment: I fixed the syntax error in the example.

Comment: Ah sorry updated answer.